# Button as spinner in android

Tags: button, spinner

I have two buttons **YES** and **NO**.

If user click on the yes Button the Dropdown menu like Spinner should appear
which contains other parameters related to Yes.

user will select one Parameter from that menu(dropdown menu)

I used this line for spinner button

**android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"**

OnClick method for Button:

```
ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            spinnerArray.add("one");
            spinnerArray.add("two");
            spinnerArray.add("three");
            spinnerArray.add("four");
            spinnerArray.add("five");
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

with this code my button is look like spinner but on Click dropdown menu not appearing.

How to do this.?????

Answer (score 0):

set your spinner launch mode to dialog `android:spinnerMode=dialog` this will display a dialog on click and let the user choose a option.

Comment: can you explain in detail..?